# how to modify the following script to be able of receive parameters with spaces?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The main idea is to copy three parameters into my fist text area called: text

```
<textarea cols="70" rows="15" id="text"  ></textarea>
```

to the press my button called: Generate tables,

```
<button id="generate">Generate tables</button><br>
```

and getting the result in the second text area called: out1,

I prove it whit the following parameters:

```
ford volvo bmw
```

and I got the right result:

```
"Svolvo|ford~E~bmw" "ford~SNRF"
```

The problem is that this time I with to receive three parameters but they could contain spaces as follows:

```
"ford  34" "volbo 45" "bmz 34"
```

So with this input I would like to produce the following desired output:

```
"Svolvo 45|ford  34~E~bmw 34" "ford~SNRF"
```

Note that the first parameter has two blank spaces and i want to preserve it in the output, when is the case, for every parameter,
However with my current regex that is:

```
/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/g
```

I am getting:

```
"S34"|"ford~E~"volbo" ""ford~SNRF" "S"bmz|45"~E~34"" "45"~SNRF"
```

Which is not right, I would like to appreciate any suggestion to fix my function:

```js
var generate = document.getElementById('generate');
var input = document.getElementById('text');
var output = document.getElementById('out1');

generate.onclick = function() {
  var text = input.value;
  text = text.replace(/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/g,
    '"S$2|$1~E~$3" "$1~SNRF"');
  output.textContent = text;
};
```

```html
<textarea cols="70" rows="15" id="text"></textarea>
<div cols="3" rows="15" id="out1" style="width:80%; white-space:pre; color:Lime"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="generate">Generate tables</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The double quotes are part of the input, or did you just write them for making clear what belongs together?

Comment: @trincot, I want to receive three parameters, due to that fact I decided that is a good Idea to ask for them inside the double quotes, but they are not part of the output, I am using them to specify every parameter, thanks for the help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regular expression, which works for the original case, but also for when you have wrapped words in double quotes, in which case the part between quotes is taken as one part:

```
/(?:"(.*?)"|(\S+))\s+(?:"(.*?)"|(\S+))\s+(?:"(.*?)"|(\S+))/g
```

The replacement string needs to change to this, as there are now more capture groups:

```
 '"S$3$4|$1$2~E~$5$6" "$1$2~SNRF"'
```

#### Explanation

This part identifies one term. It is repeated for the other two terms:

```
(?:"(.*?)"|(\S+))
```

This consists of two options split by `|`. If the string starts and ends with a quote, the first option is taken, else it goes for the second (original) option.

In both cases there is a capture group, but in the first case the double quotes are excluded. The outer brackets are only to tell the `|` operator what its scope is; it is not captured as a group (`(?:`).

```js
var generate = document.getElementById('generate');
var input = document.getElementById('text');
var output = document.getElementById('out1');

generate.onclick = function() {
  var text = input.value;
  text = text.replace(/(?:"(.*?)"|(\S+))\s+(?:"(.*?)"|(\S+))\s+(?:"(.*?)"|(\S+))/g,
    '"S$3$4|$1$2~E~$5$6" "$1$2~SNRF"');
  output.textContent = text;
};
```

```html
<textarea style="width:100%" id="text">ford "volbo 45" "bmz 34"</textarea>
<div id="out1" style="width:80%; white-space:pre; color:Lime"></div>
<button id="generate">Generate tables</button>
```

Comment: You are amazing and very good at regex, thanks for the support this was what I needed,  I really appreciate the help,

Comment: Just one question, this would work if I mix parameters with double quotes and others with not double quotes as follows?  ford "volbo 45" "bmz 34"

Comment: You're welcome. As you noticed, I had to make a correction though, so that it works with the original case as well, or any mix. See the update.

Comment: thanks this works really well but i am not sure if am doing something wrong but could you please try with this case: ford "volbo 45" "bmz 34"

Comment: This would be it: `'"Svolbo 45|ford~E~bmz 34" "ford~SNRF"' ` (see https://regex101.com/r/fM4uM7/1). Is that what you get/expect?

Comment: I would like to receive the following output: "Svolbo 45|ford~E~bmz 34" "ford~SNRF" with the past input, if it would be possible,

Comment: I am trying with this input: ford "volbo 45" "bmz 34", and i would like to get this output: "Svolbo 45|ford~E~bmz 34" "ford~SNRF"

Comment: however I am getting: "Svolbo 45|~E~bmz 34" "~SNRF"

Comment: I don't understand. Please verify your code. I will add a snippet to my answer in a minute, using this case.

Comment: Ok thanks I believe that maybe I am doing something wrong, the snippet would be very helpful to find that, I really appreciate the support and sorry for the drawbacks,

Comment: I just added the snippet, and it seems to return the result as you want it.

Comment: yes this is working so well, thanks for the support, now is clear, I really appreciate the support, thanks a lot.